# Make linearlayout scrollable

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/bag" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        style="@style/relbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="General Preference">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/settingsListView1"
        style="@style/listbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" 
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        style="@style/relbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"

        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Notification Preference">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

        <ListView style="@style/listbag" android:id="@+id/settingsListView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="100"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="15dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/radius" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip" 
            android:paddingTop="15dip" android:paddingBottom="15dip" 
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want make LinearLayout scrollable, but I don't know what use in here, I tried ScrollView but it doesn't work. I just want use scrolling only in LinearLayout not in listview. I want just make parnet layout scrollable.  Could you give me and advice for doing this.

Comment: What happened with the scrollView? Post some code. Because the basic approach is by using ScrollView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put Scrollview like this

```
<LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
 <LinearLayout>
       Your layouts
 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/bag" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    >

   <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
   >


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" style="@style/relbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" android:textSize="15dp" android:text="General Preference">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/settingsListView1" style="@style/listbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="100" android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" android:scrollbars="none" ></ListView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" style="@style/relbag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView style="@style/CodeFont" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"

            android:textSize="15dp" android:text="Notification Preference">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView style="@style/listbag" android:id="@+id/settingsListView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip" android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/radius" android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip" android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" ></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```